# Attach Facebook OG Post to your own object

Tags: facebook, api

Is there a way to attach a posts to your own OpenGraph object?  For instance, having an event object, that people can add posts too.... Or albums, or images? Seems like this might be easier done then said, but I can't seem to find anything about this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, as of now, objects we make now in the OG Protocol, can't yet have "connections" such as comments or posts.